# With ImageMagick it possible to take an image as input, and split it out into images of just its colors?

Tags: imagemagick

I included an example image of a smile.

I want to take that smile as input, and output three PNGs, where each is a separate color in the image. So for that smile it would have a yellow PNG of just the face's background, a blue PNG of the smile, and a black PNG for eyes. The image should stay the same resolution 16x16. If the image had 10 colors, there would be 10 PNGs.

Is this possible with ImageMagick?

[image]

Comment: See answer on the Imagemagick GIT forum where you asked the same question.

Answer (score 1):

This ImageMagick command will read an input image, determine how many colors it has, create a duplicate of the image for each unique color, and output an image for each color with everything transparent except that color.

```
magick input.png -background none \( +clone -unique-colors \) \
   -duplicate "%[fx:v.w-1],0" -reverse +swap \
   +transparent "%[pixel:u[-1].p{t,0}]" +delete result-%02d.png
```

If the input image has transparent pixels the output will include an image for that, also.

The output images are named with 2 digits with leading zeros... "result-NN.png".

NOTE: This command could easily create an enormous number of output images depending on the input. To make sure the output is limited to a certain number or fewer, add `-colors N` right after reading in the input image.

For Windows CLI change all the continued-line backslashes "\" to carets "^", and remove the backslashes that escape the parentheses.